# SQL Server 2012 RESTORE DATABASE leaves database with no DBO

Tags: sql-server-2012, restore

Environment:

- OS: Windows: 8.0
- SQL Server: SQL Server 2012 Express SP2
- SSMS SQL Server 2012

Steps to the problem:

- Commands executed from the nSpekUser SQL Server account which has db_creator permission but not sysadmin
- Open a query window
- Execute the following command:

  ```
  restore database [065266F14D20] from disk = 'C:\Users\rforte\AppData\Local\Temp\nSpekSqlServerBackups\065266F14D20.bak'
  with norecovery,
  move 'nSpekServer' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESSSP2\MSSQL\DATA\065266F14D20.mdf',
  move 'nSpekServer_log' to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESSSP2\MSSQL\DATA\065266F14D20.ldf'
  restore log [065266F14D20] from disk = 'C:\Users\rforte\AppData\Local\Temp\nSpekSqlServerBackups\065266F14D20.bak' with recovery
  ```
- I receive the following messages:

  ```
  Processed 3072 pages for database '065266F14D20', file 'nSpekServer' on file 1.
  Processed 4 pages for database '065266F14D20', file 'nSpekServer_log' on file 1.
  RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 3076 pages in 0.581 seconds (41.350 MB/sec).
  Processed 0 pages for database '065266F14D20', file 'nSpekServer' on file 1.
  Processed 4 pages for database '065266F14D20', file 'nSpekServer_log' on file 1.
  RESTORE LOG successfully processed 4 pages in 0.024 seconds (1.037 MB/sec).
  ```

  Indicating that all went well.  And indeed, I can see the new restored database.
- I execute:

  ```
  use [065266F14D20]
  ```

  and I get the following error:

> The server principal "nSpekUser" is not able to access the database
>   "065266F14D20" under the current security context.

- The source database comes from another computer.
- When I look at the User Mappings properties for nSpekUser from the sa account, I find that there is no dbo associated with the created database.
- If I set nSpekUser as dbo on the new database, then all is fine.
- When I grant sysadmin to the nSpekUser account before performing the restore, it all works well and I can access my database as expected.

The problem is that this sequence is normally executed from an installation procedure at a customer’s place having no account with sysadmin permission and no access to the sa account.  Thus, the installation cannot proceed normally.

**Question:**
How may I restore a database with db_creator permissions but not sysadmin and have the dbo set to the account from which I restored the database?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you have the same login on both servers, but they were created independently, so their SIDs don't match. Important because the database user has its own SID. See [this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/81858/1186), [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175475.aspx), [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1590/understanding-and-dealing-with-orphaned-users-in-a-sql-server-database/), [this](http://dbadiaries.com/using-sp_change_users_login-to-fix-sql-server-orphaned-users), [this](http://www.sqlsoldier.com/wp/sqlserver/transferring-logins-to-a-database-mirror)...

Comment: Maybe better to post this question/issue on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are right Aaron.  It turns out that SIDs were not matchng.  When they do, it works.  I am a bit puzzled however that, when you are granted dbcreator server role, SQL Server would not ensure that the user who restored the database has access to it.  What use is restoring a database that you cannot access?